# Get objects from an array along with other fields in same level, based on some condition, using mongodb aggregate

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have following data. I want to get objects from od array based on some condition. Along with that I want to get em and name field as well.

I am not very much familiar with [aggregate of mongodb](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/). So I need help to solve my problem.

```
{
_id : 1,
em : 'abc@12s.net',
name : 'NewName',
od : 
[
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("1234"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-05T13:20:10.718Z")
    },
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("2345"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
    },
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("57766"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-13T13:20:10.718Z")
    }
]       
},
{
_id : 2,
em : 'ab6c@xyz.net',
name : 'NewName2',
od : 
[
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("1234"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
    },
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("2345"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-12T13:20:10.718Z")
    },
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("57766"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-05T13:20:10.718Z")
    }
]       
}
```

I have tried using $match, $project and $unwind of aggregate to get the desired result. My query is as given below : -

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    $match : {
                    "od.ca" : {
                        '$gte': '10/05/2016',
                        '$lte': '15/05/2016'
                    }
                }
},
{
    $project:{
                    _id: '$_id',
                    em: 1,
                    name : 1,
                    od : 1
                }
},
{
    $unwind : "$od"
}, 
{
    $match : {
                    "od.ca" : {
                        '$gte': '10/05/2016',
                        '$lte': '15/05/2016'
                    }
                }
}])
```

The result I got is with em and name and od array with one of the object from od, i.e. there are multiple records for same email id.

```
 {
_id : 1,
em : 'abc@12s.net',
name : 'NewName',
od : 
[
{
    "oid" : ObjectId("57766"),
    "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-13T13:20:10.718Z")
}
]       
}
{
_id : 1,
em : 'abc@12s.net',
name : 'NewName',
od : 
[
{
    "oid" : ObjectId("2345"),
    "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
}
]       
}
```

But What I want is return result will be for each email id, inside od array all the objects matching the condition. One sample out put that I want is :-

```
 {
_id : 1,
em : 'abc@12s.net',
name : 'NewName',
od : 
[
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("2345"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-11T13:20:10.718Z")
    },
    {
        "oid" : ObjectId("57766"),
        "ca" : ISODate("2016-05-13T13:20:10.718Z")
    }
]       
}
```

Any thing wrong I am doing in the query? If the query suppose to return like this, how I can get the result I want? Can someone tell me what should I try or what changes in the query can help me getting the result I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't necessarily need a cohort of those aggregation operators except when your MongoDB version is older than the `2.6.X` releases. The **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator will do the job just fine.

Consider the following example where the **[`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/#exp._S_filter)** operator when applied in the **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage will filter the `od` array to only include documents that have a `ca` date greater than or equal to `'2016-05-10'` and less than or equal to `'2016-05-15'`:

```
var start = new Date('2016-05-10'),
    end = new Date('2016-05-15');

db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "od.ca": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "em": 1,
            "name": 1,
            "od": {
                "$filter": {
                    "input": "$od",
                    "as": "o",
                    "cond": {  
                        "$and": [
                            { "$gte": [ "$$o.ca", start ] },
                            { "$lte": [ "$$o.ca", end ] }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

Bear in mind this operator is only available for MongoDB versions `3.2.X` and newer.

---

Otherwise, for versions `2.6.X` up to `3.0.X`, you can combine the use of the **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** and **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operators to "filter" the documents in the ca array.

The **[`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/#exp._S_map)** operator basically maps some values evaluated by the **[`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/#exp._S_cond)** operator to a set of either false values or  the documents which pass the given condition. The **[`$setDifference`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setDifference/#exp._S_setDifference)** operator then returnns the difference of the sets from the previous computation. Check how this pans out with the preceding example:

```
var start = new Date('2016-05-10'),
    end = new Date('2016-05-15');

db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "od.ca": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "em": 1,
            "name": 1,
            "od": {
                "$setDifference": [
                    {
                        "$map": {
                            "input": "$od",
                            "as": "o",
                            "in": {
                                "$cond": [
                                    {  
                                        "$and": [
                                            { "$gte": [ "$$o.ca", start ] },
                                            { "$lte": [ "$$o.ca", end ] }
                                        ]
                                    },
                                    "$$o",
                                    false
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    [false]
                ]
            }
        }
    }
])
```

---

Fo versions 2.4.X and older, you may have to use the concotion of **[`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#pipe._S_match)**, **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/#pipe._S_unwind)** and **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** operators to achieve the same where the above operators do not exist.

The preceding example demonstrates this, which is what you were attempting but just left short of a **[`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#pipe._S_group)** pipeline step to group all the flattened documents into the original document schema, albeit minus the filtered array elements:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { 
        "$match": {
            "od.ca": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },  
    { "$unwind": "$od" },
    { 
        "$match": {
            "od.ca": { "$gte": start, "$lte": end }
        }
    },
    {
        "$group": {
            "$_id": "$_id",
            "em": { "$first": "$em" },
            "name": { "$first": "$name" },
            "od": { "$push": "$od" }
        }
    }
])
```

Comment: I am using 3.0.0 of mongodb. I thought of using filter initially but since it can be used with 3.0.0. Will try the solution you have given for 2.5.X to 3.0.X.

Comment: that gave me the desired result, the way I want it. @chridam

Comment: My bad, it should be `2.6.X` and not `2.5.X` as stated initially. Also, `$filter` is new in version `3.2` so it's not available for `3.0`, as a point of correction.